# Clarification: Expected number of flips required for T,H,H in any order.

Tags: probability, expected-value

If we have a coin such that $P(Heads)=p,P(Tails)=1-p$. And we continually toss until we get a at least two heads and a tails.

This is more of a clarification of a specific portion of the problem, we can condition on the outcomes of previous flips:

Let $X:=$ number of flips required to get at least two heads and one tails.

Now,

> $\displaystyle E[X] = E[X\mid H]p + E[X\mid T](1-p) = \bigg( E[X \mid H,H]p + E[X\mid T,H](1-p)\bigg)p+ E[X\mid T,T](1-p)(1-p) $.

Now if we break this up:

> $\displaystyle E[X\mid H,H] = 2+ \frac{1}{1-p}$ and $\displaystyle E[X\mid T,H] = 2+ \frac{1}{p}$

Thus we have

> $\displaystyle \bigg( E[X \mid H,H]p + E[X\mid T,H](1-p)\bigg)p = \bigg(2p+ \frac{p}{1-p}\bigg)p+\bigg(2(1-p)+ \frac{(1-p)}{1-p}\bigg)p$

This part can be simplified further but it is not the issue I am needing clarified.

Returning to the top we have the term

> $\tag{1} \displaystyle E[X\mid T,T](1-p)(1-p) $

And herein lies my confusion. The book has this term listed as being equal to

> $\tag{2} \displaystyle \bigg(1+\frac{2}{p}\bigg )(1-p)$

It seems a bit subtle, as we don't require the two heads to be consecutive; hence, it seems the $\displaystyle \frac{2}{p}$ comes from linearity of expectation. That is expected 'number of flips requires to get a heads + 'number of flips to get a heads'. And the $+1$ in their expression (2) makes sense as we have been given that a tails has occurred. However, what occurs to the extra factor of $(1-p)$ I have in my expression (1) above?

Comment: @JeanMarie In that problem the order matters, it is asking for the order of flips to be $HHT$ , where as in mine the order does not matter so long as two heads and one tails appears. That said I only need clarification in the last part of the expectation.

Comment: You are right. I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[X\mid T] = E[X\mid H T] p \ + E[X\mid TT] (1-p)$

$E[X\mid TT] = 1 + E[X\mid T]$ because we waste one flip and get back to the place from where we still need to get $2$ heads.

So, $E[X\mid T] = E[X\mid H T] p \ + (1+E[X\mid T]) (1-p)$

$\implies E[X\mid T] = \frac{1 - p}{p} + E[X\mid H T] = 1 + \frac{2}{p}$

$ \therefore (1-p)E[X\mid T] = (1 + \frac{2}{p}) (1-p)$

Comment: I was starting to think of it exactly in that manner, thank you. One last clarification. My reasoning for $\frac{2}{p}$ stemming from linearity of expectation is correct? It makes sense since we are not asking for the heads to be consecutive.

Comment: $\frac{2}{p}$ comes once we expand the term. Basically $E(HT) = \frac{1}{p}$ as we need to get one $H$ and that is $\frac{1}{p}$, of course in addition to $2$ flips we did so $2 + \frac{1}{p}$.